# Is there a way to increase how much is cached for thumbnail views of pictures?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails

If I'm looking through a folder of `.png` files for example, with "medium" set as the view size, the screen will eventually fill all the thumbnails with the appropriate pictures. But as I scroll down it takes a while for the pictures to fill in again.

I would like a way for "off screen" pictures to fill in before I get the that section of the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures will only take time the first time they are cached for thumbnail.
The cache increases as more pictures are loaded.

You cannot set the size for the cache.

You can see the currently occupied cache by selecting `Disk Cleanup...` for C drive. *(or the drive where you have installed Windows)*

After about 7000 images have been cached Windows 7 stops caching new images.
You can solve this by deleting the thumbnail cache using `Disk Cleanup...`

If your problem is that thumbnail cache is randomly being deleted and recreated then take a look at
[Thumbnail Cache Randomly Deleting and Recreating](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/9878f7db-57ff-409e-ac04-d7d678d2b629)

Comment: I think the problem might be "I want more than 7000 images cached at a time!" to which I don't think there's a solution.  (Or it's just a really slow hard drive that takes a while to pull the thumbnails.)

Comment: It sounds like the problem is actually that Jim would like the whole folder to be pre-cached, so he doesn't have to scroll to all the images to force them to load and be cached.